# using querystring to get a parameter c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi. I have this code on the first page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Game/animais/A1.xaml?anim=cabra",UriKind.Relative));
```

And on the other page I have this:

```
String anim = null;
anim = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["anim"];
```

The problem is when it gets to this code i get this error:

> anim = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["anim"]; -
>   nullreferenceexception was unhandled

I don't know what is wrong :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
Hope this will help you

```
anim = Uri.UnescapeDataString(NavigationContext.QueryString["anim"]);
```

Comment: not working, get the same error, nullreferenceexception was unhandled

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnNavigatedTo event to retreive the value of `QueryString`, NavigationContext is initialized on this event

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string anim = string.Empty;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("anim",out anim))
    {
         // do something 
    }
}
```

Comment: not working, get the same error, nullreferenceexception was unhandled

Answer (score 0):

Passing Value: In Firstpage.xaml.cs add the following

The easiest way to pass a parameter is just to use a string, something like:

```
    private void btnNavigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    string variable="test";
  string url = string.Format("/Game/animais/A1.xaml?parameter={0}", variable.toString());
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Getting Value: In another.xaml.cs add the following

Note: It is important to override the OnNavigatedTo and after that you can use the NavigationContext to get the passed parameter.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
    string parameterValue = string.Empty; 
     parameterValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];  
}
```

i think its working for you......

Comment: with this i get this
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            
            parameterValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["anim"];-keynotfoundexception was unhandled
        }

Comment: i have the exact the same thing the only difference is i use the variable anim instead of parameter

Comment: The name 'sender' does not exist in the current context 
i get this too, don't know if it is related maybe it is

Answer (score 0):

If you place your code in the Windows_Loaded event, it works.